# HTML parsing with Perl LWP gives incorrect results

Tags: perl, screen-scraping, lwp

I am trying to scrape the HTML of http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Yek+mard%2C+yek+khers&s=all. The result set contains one single result, within the class `result_text`. So I enter the link, take the text within that link, which, in this case, as Firebug shows, is `A Man, a Bear`. But strangely, the following code prints out `Yek mard, yek khers`. Can anyone help me on how to get the text which I am seeing in the browser?

```
$name = "Yek mard, yek khers";
$uri = URI->new("http://www.imdb.com/find?q=".uri_escape($name)."&s=all");
my $response = $ua->get( $uri );

my $root = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content($response->decoded_content);
@results = $root->find_by_attribute("class","result_text");
$link = $results[0]->find_by_tag_name("a");
say $link->as_HTML();
# This should print <a href="/title/tt0122857/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1">A Man, a Bear</a>
# but prints <a href="/title/tt0122857/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1">Yek mard, yek khers</a>
```

Comment: I get `Yek mard, yek khers` as well for the given URL. Can you look into the headers you are sending with your browsers, especially `Accept-Language`? The `Content-language` of the returned page may also be interesting.

Comment: Umm, I don't have any idea on how to check that, or how to set it to English when sending request.. :(

Comment: If you look at the source, there is a space before the closing a tag, don't know if it has anything to do with it but might be worth looking. Did you try something like getting all the links and then go through that with something like $href = $link->look_down(sub{ $_[0]-> tag() eq 'a'}); and then when you hit the right one, print $href->as_text

Comment: The tag, as I see in Firebug, is **<a href="/title/tt0122857/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1">A Man, a Bear</a>**. Which space are you talking about?

Comment: Firebug "cleans things up", look at the source, see the space? <a href="/title/tt0122857/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1" >A Man, a Bear</a

Comment: What difference can that possibly make? I mean, here we are getting a completely different text. If the **HTML** was improper or something, we would have got a parse error. How can we get a text which is not there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

My apologies. After looking further I have found that IMDb uses the `Accept-Language` header of the HTTP request to determine how to render the page. By default LWP doesn't send this header at all, but Firefox does, which is why my solution above works correctly.

So a solution using only `LWP` is possible. A tailored request must first be built using an [`HTTP::Request`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTTP%3a%3aRequest) object, and passed to a [`LWP::UserAgent`](https://metacpan.org/module/LWP%3a%3aUserAgent) object using the `request` method.

This code demonstrates.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';

use LWP;
use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;

my $url = 'http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Yek+mard%2C+yek+khers&s=all';

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(GET => $url, ['Accept-Language' => 'en-gb,en']);
my $resp = $ua->request($req);

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new_from_content($resp->decoded_content);
my @results = $tree->findnodes_as_strings('//td[@class="result_text"]/a/text()');

say $results[0];
```

The output is as before.

---

**Original Answer**

The problem is that the content you are seeing in your browser is generated by JavaScript code after the page has loaded. The simple combination of `LWP` and `HTML::TreeBuilder` cannot process anything other than the raw HTML returned by the site.

The usual solution recommended for this is to use the [`WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aFirefox) module, which uses a live Firefox process to fetch the HTML and JavaScript and render the page. Note that it requires the Firefox browser to be installed on your machine, and  the [`MozRepl`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/mozrepl/) Firefox addon must be installed and running.

This program shows working code that returns the result you expect. Note that I have also used [`HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder%3a%3aXPath) instead of the bare [`HTML::TreeBuilder`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder) which allows much simpler expression of the parts of the HTML you are interested in.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';

use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;
use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;

my $url = 'http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Yek+mard%2C+yek+khers&s=all';

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Firefox->new;
$mech->get($url);

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new_from_content($mech->response->content);
my @results = $tree->findnodes_as_strings('//td[@class="result_text"]/a/text()');

say $results[0];
```

**output**

```
A Man, a Bear
```

Comment: So you are saying that the raw HTML returned by the server contains **Yek mard, yek khers**, and after page load, JS converts it to **A Man, a Bear**, right? How does JS convert it? Where in the raw HTML returned by server is the string **A Man, a Bear** that we are seeing?

Comment: @Cupidvogel: I apologize. The problem is different from what I first guessed. See the update to my answer.

Comment: No need to apologize.. :) Thanks a ton!